# What is default encoding for filebeat to logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, graylog2, filebeat

I have done such configuration for specific log files for **filebeat** - files has cp1250 encoding:

```
 - 
    document_type: collector
    encoding: cp1250
    ignore_older: 672h
    log_type: log
    max_bytes: 134217728
    paths:
    - \\someserver\collector\*
```

I have done such output configuration:

```
output:
  logstash:
    compression_level: 0
    hosts:
    - localhost:5045
```

What will be encoding of **filebeat** on logstash output?

I assume that it can works like this but I think it now works like that:

```
file(cp1250) -> filebeat(utf-8) -> output(utf-8) -> logstash(utf-8) -> gralog(utf-8).
```

What is filebeat output encoding really?

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have asked 2 different questions.

**What is filebeat output encoding really?**

The event + some metadata it added.

**What will be encoding of filebeat on logstash output? / What is default encoding for filebeat to logstash?**

Filebeat uses its special `plain` encoding to read and process your text if no encoding is specified.

[From the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_encoding)

> The `plain` encoding is special, because it does not validate or transform any input.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow since not analyzed metadata from logstash.